Autofill multiple columns in VBA
I want to autofill multiple non-adjacent columns using VBA. I have tried a few things and am currently trying a for loop to loop through each column to autofill each successively. My For loop is not working.
Code:
  Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    Selection.Formula = "=IF(RC[2]<0,RC[1]*-1,RC[1])"
    
'    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    
    Dim cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In Selection.Cells
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=cel.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    Next cel

Selection: 
I get

Run-time error 1004
AutoFill method of Range class failed

What's wrong with my for loop? Or, how else can I do this?
I left in the commented line as my first failed attempt

Please, try the next code not needing iteration:
Sub AutofilDiscRange()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Intersect(Selection.EntireColumn, ws.rows(Selection.row & ":" & lastR)).Formula = _
                                                          "=IF(RC[2]<0,RC[1]*-1,RC[1])"
End Sub


No need for auto-fill here - you can assign the formula directly.
Try this:
Sub Tester()
    Dim lRow As Long, c As Range, sel As Range
    
    Set sel = Selection
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each c In sel.Cells
        c.Resize(1 + (lRow - c.Row)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<0,RC[1]*-1,RC[1])"
    Next c
End Sub

